# Error as Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am getting the following error on click of a button [image: input string was not in a correct format],

On click of a button i am calling the following method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for pdfgeneration
/// </summary>
public class pdfgeneration
{
    public pdfgeneration()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public void pdfgenerator(String name1, AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor Editor1)
    {

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        // Create PDF document
        Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 70, 55, 40, 25);

        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, new FileStream("e://" +name1 + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);

        pdfDocument.Open();
        string htmlText = Editor1.Content;
        System.Collections.Generic.List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), null);

        for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
        {
            pdfDocument.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
        }

        pdfDocument.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

}
```

the stack trace is:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +7471335
   System.Number.ParseSingle(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +115
   System.Single.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +192
   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper..ctor(String tag, ChainedProperties chain) +148
   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLTagProcessor_TD.StartElement(HTMLWorker worker, String tag, IDictionary`2 attrs) +84
   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.StartElement(String tag, Dictionary`2 attrs) +79
   iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.ProcessTag(Boolean start) +30
   iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.Go(TextReader reader) +1008
   iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.Parse(ISimpleXMLDocHandler doc, ISimpleXMLDocHandlerComment comment, TextReader r, Boolean html) +48
   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(TextReader reader, StyleSheet style, IDictionary`2 tags, Dictionary`2 providers) +94
   iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(TextReader reader, StyleSheet style) +9
   pdfgeneration.pdfgenerator(String name1, Editor Editor1) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dcis\App_Code\pdfgeneration.cs:37
   EntryForm.Button4_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dcis\EntryForm.aspx.cs:224
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

How can I resolve this error?

@ geek for error in the code he has posted

[image]

Comment: There's no problem in your code part, the problem is while you are calling the function, may be it sounds you are not giving the correct arguments at the function call.

Comment: If I am getting you correctly you want to convert webpage to pdf.Am I right?

Comment: @geek Ya i want to convert the content in Editor(Ajax Control) to pdf, it contains html text.

Comment: @Ishan:You tried my solution?

Comment: @geek ShowPdf() does not exist in the current context error comes.

Comment: @Ishan:I have updated the my answer

Comment: @geek Please check my original question, for error in your above given code.

Comment: @IShan:Share your html content

Comment: @geek http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856484/error-converting-html-text-to-a-pdf-file-using-itextsharp-in-asp-net this solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public void CreatePDFDocument(string strHtml)
    {

        string strFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("test.pdf");
        // step 1: creation of a document-object
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2:
        // we create a writer that listens to the document
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create));
        StringReader se = new StringReader(strHtml);
        HTMLWorker obj = new HTMLWorker(document);
        document.Open();
        obj.Parse(se);
        document.Close();
        ShowPdf(strFileName);



    }







public void ShowPdf(string strFileName)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.WriteFile(strFileName);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Please check my original question, for error in your above given code.

Answer (score 9):

I have facing same error, **"Input string was not in a correct format."**, i check my html string and found that, if i write table width outside of style tag, i get this error,
For eg,   :- Give error at htmlWorker.Parse() method.

when i put width tag in style tag, i resolve this error, 
For eg,

I hope, this will help you little bit.

```
For eg, <table width="610px"> </table> :- Give error at htmlWorker.Parse() method.
```

when i put width tag in style tag, i resolve this error,

```
For eg, <table style="width:610px"> </table>
```

I hope, this will help you little bit.

Answer (score 3):

You could start by narrowing it down *within* `pdfgenerator`... Enabling build symbols for that dll would be a start, but even some simple tracing so that you can tell where it got to when it exploded would help.

Ultimately `PdfWriter` isn't core .NET, so you will have to help us narrow it down.

Or even simpler: hit "Start Debugging", and put a break-point on that method; now step through and see a: where it explodes, and b: what the key values are at that point.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you've got a non-numeric style value where iTextSharp is expecting a number.  "font-size:normal" or something like that.

`CellWrapper(String, ChainedProperties)` is looking at the `HtmlTags.WIDTH`.  Here's the source from iTextSharp 5.0.6:

```
    public CellWrapper(String tag, ChainedProperties chain) {
        this.cell = CreatePdfPCell(tag, chain);
        String value = chain[HtmlTags.WIDTH];
        if (value != null) {
            value = value.Trim();
            if (value.EndsWith("%")) {
                percentage = true;
                value = value.Substring(0, value.Length - 1);
            }
            width = float.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
```

It looks an awful lot like the problem is in the float.Parse() call.  It looks like this code can't handle anything but '%' or a bald number.  If your width is defined in 'cm', 'px', or whatever, that may well be the problem.

Use the Source!

PS: What version are you using?  IIRC, iText has been shipping with debug info for quite some time.  If all else fails, just build a debug version yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem you had and I found another solution.

That error occurs when it tries to parse a size with the "px" part. To solve it, just replace the HTML string "px" occurences for "". It still knows that it is pixels.

Hope it works on your case!