# Error converting HTML text to a pdf file using itextsharp in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, itext, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I am using the following code to convert contents in Editor(Ajax control) to pdf,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for pdfgeneration
/// </summary>
public class pdfgeneration
{
    public pdfgeneration()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public void pdfgenerator(String name1, AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor Editor1)
    {

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        // Create PDF document
        Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 70, 55, 40, 25);

        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, new FileStream("e://" +name1 + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);

        pdfDocument.Open();
        string htmlText = Editor1.Content;
        System.Collections.Generic.List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), null);

        for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
        {
            pdfDocument.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
        }

        pdfDocument.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }


}
```

I am initially hard coding the following HTML text in the Editor(Ajax control),

```
String editorcontent = "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>" +
                 "<br/>" + "<P align='center'><b>" + courtname + "</b></P>"
                + "<br/><P align='center'>(Before" + jname + "," + desname + ")"
                + "<br/>" + "<P align='right'><b><u>" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem + " no. " + TextBox1.Text + "/" + TextBox2.Text + "</u></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</P>"
                + "<br />"
  **//this table is the problem//**    + "<table><tr><td width='750px'><p align='left'>" + petitioner + "</p>" + "</td><td>" + "<p align='right'>" + "..Applicant" + "</p>" + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td><p align='center'>" + "V/s" + "</p>" + "</td><td></td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr><td width='75px'><p align='left'>" + respondent + "</p>" + "</td><td>" + "<p align='right'>" + "..Respondent" + "</p>" + "</td></tr></table>"
                + "<br/><P align='center'><b><u>ORDER</u></b>";
            Editor1.Content = editorcontent;
```

If i remove the following `table` from the above code than the pdf is generated successfully. but once i include that `table` in my HTMl code i get the following Error

[image]

How to resolve my problem.

Comment: add <tbody></tbody> may be work.

Comment: @Govind KamalaPrakash Malviya where exactly?

Comment: <table><tbody> ....  </tbody></table>

Comment: @Govind KamalaPrakash Malviya Sorry that did not work.

Comment: Exact duplicate question from same user.  Grr.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error as Input string was not in a correct format.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828650/error-as-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the current version of iTextSharp does **not** support cell width specified with 'px'. it ***does*** support percentage or numeric-only width cell widths.

when you tried hard-coding the HTML content, there was 'px' in two places:

1. `<td width='750px'>`
2. `<td width='75px'>`

remove 'px' and you'll be OK.